# Make a window transparent and pass through mouse clicks

Tags: macos

Is there a program for Mac OS X that could make a window

- be on top
- ignore mouse clicks and
- have some transparency

I essentially want to turn any window into tracing paper.  It's important for the window to ignore clicks so that the window directly underneath will receive them.

No, doing this all within photoshop isn't a solution for me.

Comment: Wouldn't it work as well to have the window receiving the mouse clicks be semi-transparent and on top? You could still see the information in both top and bottom windows.

Comment: This should be an answer!  Yep, thanks you're absolutely right and I found a utility that does just that.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Garyjohn is absolutely right, this is much simpler if you make the window that should receive the clicks transparent (and place what you're referencing underneath).

I'm giving a utility called [Afloat](http://infinite-labs.net/afloat/) a try but I imagine this is commonly available functionality.

Answer (score 1):

on Mac there is app called 
[Overlay](http://mac.brothersoft.com/overlay-download.html)

But it makes transparent only image files.

For windows there is very nice application GhostIt it works with any window. I like it. And it's free.
[GhostIt](http://download.cnet.com/Ghost-It/3000-2072_4-10077652.html)